# How to protect furniture in a leaky garage?

Tags: garage, furniture

I have some furniture (nothing very valuable, but some tables and bookcases) that I am temporarily going to have to store in a garage that is a bit leaky.

It's not very leaky, and there is some chance it won't leak at all during the 6 months I need to store the furniture there. On occasion water will come through the roof at random spots, but at most it would rise to maybe 1mm.

What sort of wrapping is most appropriate to give the furniture a fair chance of protection? If the furniture was destroyed by rain it would not be a big loss, but I'm keen to find some cheap way of protecting it if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put the furniture up on blocks.  Simple blocks of cheap wood.  "1 inch" (meaning 3/4") strips are fine.

You don't need to avoid water ever contacting the furniture, but you do need anything that does to dry out quickly.  For that reason, wrapping in any form of plastic is likely harmful.

Now drape some plastic loosely over the top, or a cheap tarp, making sure there's plenty of airflow.  Done.

Comment: even a few pvc pipe struts here and there to create a tent effect, as long as no pooling will be created.

Comment: Regardless of its value, if you’re going to the trouble of storing it, I would place it on wood blocks, cover with an old blanket or towels (humidity) and then a dollar store tarp. As a retired veteran, I have moved and stored more things, in more climates than you can imagine.